# Change the Apple login account for iPhone developer programme

Tags: iphone

Recently I have registered for the iPhone developer program with an Email ID, but now I want to changer my login ID to some other email ID. Is it possible to change it now?

Answer (score 1):

You could try following [Apple's instructions for changing the e-mail address associated with your AppleID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5621?viewlocale=en_US).